# Getting STRING Characters value before a character occuring more than once in php

Tags: php, string, variables, character, strlen

I want to get the value of the last word from a varaible.....

if the variable has a content of ,book,farm,chop,cook

i want to get the value of cook alone after the last , in php

```
$valt = ",book,farm,chop,cook";
```

or to get the value from the right hand side before a ',' is encountered...
Thanks

Comment: Explode on `,`?

Comment: Or a memory efficient way to search for `,` from right and do a substr() if you reach a `,` or index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`strrchr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) and a [`ltrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) to tidy up you could do this

```
$valt = ",book,farm,chop,cook";
echo ltrim(strrchr($valt,','),',');
```

Result

```
cook
```

Comment: Also need to handle the case if `,` is not found?

Comment: Ok, apparently, it's handled by adding a `,` at the start.

Answer (score 3):

Use `explode()` to convert from string to array and use `end()`.

```
   <?php
   $arr = ",book,farm,chop,cook";
   $a = explode(',', $arr);
   print_r(end($a));
```

Comment: You dont need to add `exit;`

Answer (score 2):

Optional solution with `strrpos` which finds position of **last** occurence of `,`. After that you can use `substr` to get a substring starting from the **next** position:

```
$str = ",book,farm,chop,cook";
print_r(substr($str, 1 + strrpos($str, ',')));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$valt = ",book,farm,chop,cook";
$r = explode(",",$valt);
$a = array_key_last($r);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: This returns `4` and not `cook`

Comment: Please consider adding some "text". An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.